# Ionic header..how to remove 3 dots and make all header visible?

Tags: css, user-interface, ionic-framework, heading

I have hader with text, on iPhone 4 and some others Android devices is part of the heading text trimmed and replaced by 3 dots (see screenshot below).

How can i remove this limitation please? Text could be normally displayed if will be moved a little bit on the left side.

[image]

Many Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically it is not called 3 dots. The `text-overflow` property has been set to `ellipsis`, `overflow is hidden` and `white-space` has `nowrap`

Override these properties in the `.bar .title` class.